# Selecting HTML body when contained element exists

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a component on page that can be moved around via drag-and-drop method. What I'd like to be able to do is set the **body** tag to `user-select:none` while an item is being dragged.

Something like this (metaphorically as the `<` selector is make-believe):

```
 body < .sortable-item.is-dragging {
      user-select: none;
 }
```

Comment: You will have to wait for CSS4 before implementing that: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational

Comment: oh bummer. thanks for your help though. If you want to put this in as the answer I will tick it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently CSS3 does not support this parent relative selector. You will have to wait for CSS4 before implementing that: [**CSS4 :has() pseudo-class draft**](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational)

---

Alternatively if you are looking for a jQuery solution, you can use `:has()` selector.

```js
$('.container:has(.sortable)').css('user-select', 'none');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sortable">
      Not selectable
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="not-sortable">
      Selectable text
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```